# Sort an Elasticsearch result by a specific, manually defined pattern

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch query which is fairly big. Paraphrasing, this query returns matching "consultants" and sorts them in the following fashion:

- distance

  - *based on their office, consultants can share offices and have the exact same distance value, consultants at the nearest office show first)*
- office leaders

  - *boolean field, consultant is a leader or they are not, this sort will push office leaders to the top of their office "grouping"*
- all remaining consultants

By way of example, for me (based in London) I might get something like this:

```
1. [London office leader]
2. [London consultant]
3. [London consultant]
4. [London consultant]
5. [Paris office leader]
6. [Paris consultant]
7. ...etc
```

My challenge here is to ensure that the "all remaining consultants" section contains a balanced mix of males and females (i.e we don't have a group of men, then a group of women, but rather have them more evenly spread).

I have tried using a script sort to "boost" consultants with a `gender === F || id is odd` calculation; the idea was that all women would be boosted, and a percentage of men would also be boosted. However, this doesn't work very well and results in "clumping" of women (i.e a man, followed by nine females, then two men and then the other females).

I am open to suggestions, but my current idea as to how to approach this is to manually specify a "pattern", e.g. something like:

```
MFMFMMFMFFFMFMMFFMFMMFMFFFMFMF
```

and have ES sort the results so that the pattern is satisfied.

My end goal is to sort something like this:

```
London
    leaders (sorted by M/F pattern)
    others (sorted by M/F pattern)
Paris
    leaders (sorted by M/F pattern)
    others (sorted by M/F pattern)
```

This is where I'm a little stuck - I'm sure I can write a `script` sort, but I think I need context outside of the document currently being sorted, e.g. a global reference to know what has already been sorted.

The result set is paginated so my solution needs to ensure that the order is the same every time (or at least consistent for the session).

Any help appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the direction of a specific algorithm which I've not thought of.